# Limit to infinity involving trigonometric functions

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to find a more general way to determine limits of this kind:

$$
\lim_{t\to -\infty} \frac{2-t+\sin t}{t + \cos t}=-1
$$

So I just learned that *the* limit neither $\cos t$ or $\sin t$ exists, but can I **think** of these limits as e.g. $\lim_{t\to \pm\infty} \sin t \in [-1,1]$?

Following this logic, is it reasonable to neglect the $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ assuming their value must lie in the interval $[-1,1]$ when $t$ goes to $\pm \infty$?

If I am not mistaken this solution ends up being $-1$ because the limit ends up looking like this when neglecting the $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ when $t \to \pm \infty$.
$$
\lim_{t \to - \infty} \frac{2-t}{t}=-\frac{\infty}{\infty}= -1
$$

Comment: Hint : $2-t+\sin t=t(-1+2/t+\sin(t)/t)$ and $t+\cos(t)=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{t\to -\infty} \frac{2-t+\sin t}{t + \cos t}=
\lim_{t\to -\infty} \frac{t(\frac{2}{t}-1+\frac{\sin t}{t})}{t(1 + \frac{\cos t}{t})}=-1
$$
since it is sufficient to observe that:

1)$\frac{2}{t}\to 0$.

2)$\frac{\sin t}{t}$ and $\frac{\cos t}{t}$ go to $0$ since are both of them the product between a function that goes to $0$ ($\frac{1}{t}$) and a bounded function ($\cos t$ and $\sin t$).

Comment: Well that clarified how to solve this, thank you!